# Result does not return any data in FMDB

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, fmdb

I am using [this](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/836_Persisting_iOS_Application_Data_in_SQLite_Database_Using_FMDB.aspx) tutorial to implement FMDB in my project. But my code does not return any value. here is the code for retrive value.

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getCustomers
{
    NSMutableArray *customers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Utility getDatabasePath]];
    [db open];
    FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM customers"];
    NSLog(@"results %i,%@,%@",[results intForColumn:@"id"],[results stringForColumn:@"firstname"],[results stringForColumn:@"lastname"]);
    while([results next]) 
    {
        Customer *customer = [[Customer alloc] init];
        customer.customerId = [results intForColumn:@"id"];
        customer.firstName = [results stringForColumn:@"firstname"];
        customer.lastName = [results stringForColumn:@"lastname"];
        [customers addObject:customer];
    }
    [db close];
    return customers; 
}
```

When i check for db than db exist at document directory here is log

```
CRUD[47363:f803] db /Users/pingdanehog/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/D9F19E7D-A232-4C4A-8218-58BC136053A7/Documents/Customers.db
```

Here is my db
[image]

And it contain data

[image]

But my resulset value always be null please help this code have run before but when i create new db with same name for this project than it have stopped.

Here is the value of result.

```
results 0,(null),(null)
```

I have initialize my DB in appdelegate file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    databaseName = @"Customers.db";

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    [self createAndCheckDatabase];


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void) createAndCheckDatabase
{
    BOOL success;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    if(success) return;

    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
}
```

Comment: you open database from /Users/pingdanehog/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/D9F19E7D-A232-4C4A-8218-58BC136053A7/Documents/Customers.db this or from project folder (directory)

Comment: @DharaParekh I am copy customer.db when application first time load into document directory and check that is thair already exist or not.

Comment: @DharaParekh check my question now i have edited code i used to copy database in document directory

Comment: databaseWithPath method creates a database for you if it does not exist already. You should not do it by using NSFileManager.

Comment: if possible then first check with NSString *dbPath = @"/Users/Tech/Desktop/Farm/Database/Farm.sqlite" means path of db of your project directory.

Answer (score 1):

What happens, if you place the line

> > NSLog(@"results %i,%@,%@",[results intForColumn:@"id"], ....

behind the [results next], e.g. inside the while loop?

The documentation of FMDB says:
"You must always invoke -[FMResultSet next] before attempting to access the values returned in a query, even if you're only expecting one"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have initialized your db into AppDelegate or any of your file where you are using FMDB.

If yes & you have initialized it somewhere, then try to run this SQL "SELECT * FROM customers" . in database itself, in SQL tab. And check whether database contains the values or not.

```
Before that make sure you are running SQL in databse which resides into **Application Support**
```

Enjoy Programming!

Comment: Yes i have initialized my db in appdelegate file chaeck my question now i have edited it

Comment: But isnt it easy to use FMDB in stead of actual SQL query. and thats not my downvote.

Comment: No,by SQL, I meant run this query into the software which you have used for creating db.For ex, mesaSQLite or SQLite Manager or from terminal itself